# Different ways of operating an infinite continued fraction

Tags: problem-solving, continued-fractions

Given the continued fraction below,
$$
\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cdots}+\cfrac{1}{\cdots}}+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cdots}+\cfrac{1}{\cdots}}}
$$
I wanted to know to which number it converged, so I formulated and solved presumably without any mistake the following equation:
$$
x=\frac{1}{x+x}\\
\vdots\\
x=\sqrt{\frac12}
$$
After that, I tried to formulate the equation in a different way to see what happened and so I did. But for some reason I couldn't find one solution although I think it's also correctly formulated.
$$
x=\frac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}\\
\vdots\\
0x=0
$$
So, as you can see, there are infinitely many solutions. And this same phenomenum keeps happening if we move the $x$ with which I mean that we could find a solution for this expression:
$$
\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}}
$$
But not for this one:
$$
x=\frac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}}+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x+x}+\cfrac{1}{x+x}}}}\\
$$
My question is: why does that happen? Thanks!

Comment: Before determining a value to which something converges, you have to first prove that it converges. Have you shown this?

Comment: Your second evaluation is not correct. It becomes the tautology, $$x = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+x}+\frac{1}{x+x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = x$$ Same with the fourth one.

Comment: @SamDeHority how can I prove it?

Comment: How do you define the limit of this?

Comment: @tito 0x = 0 is also a tautology, so the evaluation is not necessarily incorrect.

Comment: What is the definition of such a tree-shaped continued fraction in the first place?

Comment: Imagine that instead of division you have addition. $x=1+(x+x)$. Does this mean that $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty1=$ $=-1$ ? :-)